# MySQL - query that should filter based on records contained in the join table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

**studentTable**:

| id | studentName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |
| 2 | Name2 |
| 3 | Name3 |

**studentCourseTable**:

| id | studentId | courseId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |

I want to (let's say) list students who have taken courseId 1 AND 3 (together) BUT have NOT taken 2. Or any dynamic combination such as that, like courseId 1,2,3 should be taken; 1,2 not taken but 3 is taken etc etc.

I have tried some JOIN clause to filter but have not been able to apply more than 1 condition:

```
SELECT student.* 
FROM      studentTable AS s
LEFT JOIN studentCourseTable AS sc 
       ON sc.studentId = s.id
WHERE sc.studentId IN (1,3)
  AND sc.studentId NOT IN (2)
```

or:

```
SELECT student.* 
FROM      studentTable AS s
LEFT JOIN studentCourseTable AS sc 
       ON sc.studentId = s.id 
      AND sc.courseId IN (1, 3) 
      AND sc.courseId IN (2)
```

The important thing is that I want to find students that take specified courses TOGETHER, AND not take any other specified course. The student may take more courses than specified (as long as it is not in NOT taken list).

**Edit for some clarifications: ** For example if I say the student should take (2,4) but NOT (3), returning a student that takes (2,4,5) is ok. But (2,3) or (2,4,5) are NOT ok.

There are some other tables that I'm joining the student table with, not sure if it matters but this is the gist of it.

Can anyone assist me with this?

** Edit: ** [@lemon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73388666/7845872) has cracked it. Here's the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjC9zTBNpehz7BtkddWLak/0) he made, which lists any user that attended 1 OR 3 AND have not attended 2. Here's my [updated demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjC9zTBNpehz7BtkddWLak/2) which lists students that attended 1 AND 3 AND have not attended 2.

Thanks to all who helped me, this was superb.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you looked into JOIN's with where clause?

Comment: @NicoHaase please see the edit for some examples that I've tried.

Comment: @Brad please see the edit for some examples that I've tried.

Comment: @philipxy I don't see how I can apply this exactly, tried some things myself as mentioned but couldn't come up with a solution.

Comment: Don't just dump wrong code. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: The Q&A duplicate link applies to the 1st query you gave. It "turns left join into inner join": it gives the same result if LEFT is dropped. PS [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: When pinned down you will have a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all information from your students and use two kind of `JOIN` operations:

- an `INNER JOIN` for each due attended course
- a `LEFT JOIN` for non-attended courses, to be filtered out in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM students s
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT studentId FROM courses WHERE courseId = 1) c1
        ON s.id = c1.studentId
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT studentId FROM courses WHERE courseId = 3) c3
        ON s.id = c3.studentId
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT studentId FROM courses WHERE courseId IN (2)) not_c
        ON s.id = not_c.studentId
WHERE not_c.studentId IS NULL
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjC9zTBNpehz7BtkddWLak/3).

---

Another option is to count

- positively your needed courses
- negatively your unneeded courses

Eventually sum up the values, and filter out those students whom don't have sum equal to the amount of needed courses.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM       courses  c 
INNER JOIN students s
        ON s.id = c.studentId
GROUP BY s.id, 
         s.studentName
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.courseId IN (1,3) THEN  1
                WHEN c.courseId IN (2)   THEN -1 END) = 2
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjC9zTBNpehz7BtkddWLak/6).

Comment: I tried this before I believe. But I want to see students who have taken courses 1 AND 3 together, not just either of them.

Comment: Then one option is to use a `JOIN` for each of your "*course_id*". Check the updated answer.

Comment: Ok, I think I've fixed the mentioned issue by using a new `INNER JOIN` for each MUST ATTEND course. See the [updated demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjC9zTBNpehz7BtkddWLak/2) for the mentioned changes.

Thanks a lot, this was brilliant.

Comment: yeap, that was the way to go. I updated the demo myself with the mentioned changes and marked your answer as accepted. Thanks lemon.

Answer (score 1):

To get only students that are in groups 1 and 3

```
SELECT s.studentName
from studenttable AS s
INNER JOIN studentCourseTable AS sc ON sc.studentId = s.id
where sc.courseId in (1,3)
group by s.id
having count(*) = 2;
```

We first should group by student name or id, then we get only those that are in the 2 courses by adding "having count(*) = 2"

Comment: Where is the condition: "...BUT have NOT taken 2"?

Comment: This seems good to filter the students that have taken the courses 1 and 3, but I also want to filter students that have not taken course 2 for example. Also the student may be allowed to take other courses as long as I don't specify that they should not take it.

Comment: No need to add 'AND sc.courseId <> 2' since we have forced the select to take only groups 1 and 3.

Comment: On where clause you can add your combinations, if for example you want to select students with courses (1,2,3) then the having count(*) should equal 3

Comment: I believe this will take any student that attends courses 1 or 3, so the count can be greater than just 2, no?

I need to find any student that attend courses BOTH 1 AND 3, BUT NOT 2.